# Syncing view item positioning in two AdapterViews

Tags: android

I have two AdapterViews that display horizontal images.  When I scroll right or left on one of the adapter views, I want the other adapter view in sync. That is I want it to move along with the other one. Since the adapters just return what the AdapterView's request, I don't think the adapters are enough of a hook into this.  Because something must make the other adapter refresh and request the same item positions.

So for example if 3 items are visible in both views and there are 100 more in each, if I scroll once it will request item (1,2,3) but the other one will be on (0,1,2).  How do I issue an event or call a method on an AdapterView to make it move left or right? Normally it catches a button click or something but in this case, I'm really not issuing a button click left or right on the other adapter.

Update: Actually, I'd settle for or just like to know how to move items programatically within one AdapterView as opposed to handling onTouch events.

Comment: thanks for rushing to answer guys. I've posted the soln below.

Answer (score 0):

Just overload onTouchEvent(View, keyCode, KeyEvent) and catch this using View.onKeyEvent listener.  then sync the views.  Key reference to each view.  check if view passed into onKeyEventListener is same as the one to sync with.